# My Class.cpp is not being seen by the linker

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-code

I am trying to write a C++ class in a separate header and cpp file using VS Code as my IDE with the 'run' and 'C++' extensions.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Fan.h"

int main() {
    Fan fan1;    
    return 0;
}
```

**Fan.h**

```
#ifndef FAN_H
#define FAN_H

class Fan {
    public:
        Fan();
};
#endif
```

**Fan.cpp**

```
#include "Fan.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Fan::Fan() {
    cout << "Fan Class" << endl;
}
```

I really can't seem to find anything popping out as obviously wrong. I am wondering if it is a setup problem with VS Code.

If I change #include "Fan.h" in main.cpp to "Fan.cpp" it works so it makes me think that the code works but that the linker is not setup right.

Would appreciate any help!

EDIT: Ok so I've tried the code in a different IDE and it worked. It's something to do with VS Code. Here is the error:

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\<USER>\Desktop\Fan\" && g++ tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp -o tempCodeRunnerFile && "c:\Users\<USER>\Desktop\Fan\"tempCodeRunnerFile
C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Temp\cclMFKxO.o:tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `Fan::Fan()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Perhaps a make file is expecting a .cop or something other than what's being provided.

Comment: It is not 'something to do with VS code'. It is something to do with not including your source file in the VS project correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the IDE is only compiling `main.cpp`. You need to find the command that is compiling `main.cpp` and ensure that it also compiles `fan.cpp` into `fan.obj`. You will also need to ensure that both `main.obj` and `fan.obj` are passed to the linker (which produces the executable program, `main.exe` or whatever).

There are two steps involved here:

1. cpp -> obj (compiling each source file into a matching object file)
2. obj -> exe (linking many object files into an executable)

Comment: I've gone through and found that yes VS Code is only compiling my main.cpp file and is not compiling Fan.cpp

I think I will just be better off getting a better C++ IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I would say to make a CMakeLists.txt file and add main.cpp and fan.cpp into the add_executable section. Then VS can handle and run files through CMake.